# How to open item.url in browser using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In Ionic framework I want to open below link in system browser how can I do that.

```
<a class="button" href="{{item.url}}" >Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
<a href="{{ item.url }}" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank'); return false;"> Click me!</a>
```

And you must install plugin [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/). 
Run command: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

I hope to help you with my answer above!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) .

**View**

```
 <a class="button" ng-click="openLink(item.url)">Click Me</a>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.openLink = function (url) {
        var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }
```